# Storing and displaying a large amount of time based scheduling information in a web app

Tags: database-design, web-applications, calendar, data-visualization

My project involves storing large amounts of multi day events.

The data then needs to be displayed in a large table on a web page, similar to a calendar type application but with finer detail. However, obviously the faster my pages can load the better!

A basic screen might display 10 rows of subjects and 10 columns of days.

Each day can be split into half day segments. Each half day, there may be 3 or 4 activities, each activity may have a status, each subject may be available or unavailable etc.

Obviously, I don't want to perform 100/200 database queries to summarise the activities and subject for each half day.

**1. Are there existing examples of applications which store, summarise and display large amounts of time based information?**

**2. What apps display complex data such as this effectively**

Comment: Have you seen Google Calendar? https://www.google.com/calendar

Comment: Why can't you retrieve all that data with a single SQL statement instead of using several hundred?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a variation of a gantt chart without the dependencies between the events.

My suggestion would be to look at images of various gantt charts on Google images and see if that's what you're looking for.

To answer your first question somewhat, calendar applications don't usually store multi-day events as multiple rows in a data store.  The application can calculate the intermediate days if you have the start and end date.